# How do I roll a dice multiple times without getting same result using the Random method?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace DieRoller
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < 20; a = a + 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(RollDie());

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static int RollDie()
        {
            Random roll = new Random();
            int test = roll.Next(1, 6 + 1);
            return test;
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute this code I get the number 4 multiple times or the number 2 multiple times...etc.

Isn't it supposed to execute the RollDie function for each iteration of the loop? and isn't that supposed to yield a different value each time? pls halp!

EDIT: The thing is guys, I need to generate the randomness only inside the RollDie method, and I can't have any arguments for the RollDie method (Basically I have to generate the randomness only using the random method inside the RollDie method), other questions don't address that.

Comment: When you create new instances of Random in quick succession they'll often end up with the same seed, resulting in the same values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments for explanation of *why* it doesn't work.  Here a possible way to make it work:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Random roll = new Random();
    for (int a = 0; a < 20; a = a + 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(RollDie(roll));

    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static int RollDie(Random roll)
{
    int test = roll.Next(1, 6 + 1);
    return test;
 }
```

Or, for simplicity, just:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Random roll = new Random();
    for (int a = 0; a < 20; a = a + 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(roll.Next(1, 6 + 1));

    }
    Console.ReadLine();
 }
```